# How can i enable the sound on Ubuntu in Vmware?

Tags: sound, vmware

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 on VMware and I can't make the sound work for some reason. I get this message from VMware:

```
A device ID has been used that is out of range for your system.
Sound will be disconnected.
```

I want to be able to solve all this kind of problems in order to make a fully usable OS so I can deploy it at PCs at work.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a Windows host: As the Vmware knowledge base [states](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2086551), you need to enable stereo mix:

> Solution
>   Enabling "Stereo Mix" on Windows host fixes the problem. The stereo mix option is seen under "Recording" tab of sound settings. If it's not seen, install the specific sound card driver for the underlying physical sound card based on its manufacturer. Once the stereo mix option is available, it needs to be enabled for the scenarios where we specify the host sound card for the VM in its sound card settings explicitly. If the default host sound card is used, there will be no sound issues and hence no need of enabling the stereo mix. 
>   It's important to select "Listen to this device" for "stereo mix" under the "Listen" tab of its properties. The same applies to the microphone as well. These are part of the sound settings.
>
> Select the playback device for the microphone to be based on the installed physical sound card driver. For example, if the driver is from Realtek, then it would be "Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio)." And for the stereo mix, this would be "Default Playback Device." This set up is necessary to get the recording to work with stereo mix enabled.
>
> After all of the above steps, while specifying the host sound card in the VM settings, speakers either based on the real headset connected or the physical sound card driver can be selected. The resolution proposed above works for
>   both.
>
> Note: It's necessary to check that the guest sound card drivers are installed and set up properly. For this, selecting the default host sound card in the VM setting is recommend to check that the necessary sound drivers are installed for the guest so that both playback and recording works.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a fairly easy, but a counterintuitive, way of playing audio on any Linux VM that supports Pulseaudio. It will also work on any VM platform, not just Hyper-V.

And the best thing about it is that it doesn't require changing any system setting on either the VM or the host machine. And it doesn't require you to run your VM in an enhanced session either and share your host system's audio drivers with it.

**Short answer:**

Install OS-appropriate version of `ffmpeg` utility on both your host machine and the VM.

Run the following command on your host machine:

```
ffplay -nodisp -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -analyzeduration 0 -probesize 32 -f s16le -i udp://0.0.0.0:18181?listen=1
```

Run the following command on your VM:

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -i "remote.monitor" -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -f s16le "udp://IP.OF.YOUR.HOST:18181"
```

**Detailed answer:**

This article provides a more detailed guidance of the process and explains what the commands actually do: [GETTING AUDIO WORKING ON UBUNTU VM ON HYPER-V](https://scientificprogrammer.net/2020/11/24/getting-audio-working-on-ubuntu-vm-on-hyper-v/)